# NSNotificationCenter - removing observer when observed objected is deallocated

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I use the following line to add an observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.playerItem];
```

My observer (`self`) will never be deallocated.

But when the user starts playing a different item, the old `self.playerItem` will be deallocated---but will always be replaced with a new one, which I want to continue observing.

When that happens, what happens in regards to my observer's status as an observer? Do I need to do something to stop observing the deallocated object, as is required with KVO? Or will I continue observing the new object at `self.playerItem`? Or will my observer automatically be "unregistered?"

If I need to remove the observer, I wonder why there's no corresponding `removeObserver` method that enables one to specify a selector; it seems I can remove an observer only wholesale via `removeObserver:(id)notificationObserver`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`NSNotificationCenter` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver%3aselector%3aname%3aobject%3a):

> Be sure to invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object:
>   before notificationObserver or any object specified in
>   addObserver:selector:name:object: is deallocated.

So: you should unregister your observer before `self.playerItem` deallocated.

> But when the user starts playing a different item, the old
>   self.playerItem will be deallocated---but will always be replaced with
>   a new one, which I want to continue observing.

You may pass `nil` as the last parameter of `addObserver:selector:name:object:` method:

> Adds an entry to the receiver’s dispatch table with an observer, a notification selector and optional criteria: notification name and sender.
>   If you don't specify
>
> If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.

So you will receive notification `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` from any object that posts it.

Comment: Cool, so I can specify object:nil and then I won't need to worry about ever removing the observer. Thanks!

Comment: Not really. You still should remove observer when you not interested in further notification processing. But you may do this only once instead of unregistering/registerint for each item.

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 9 it is no longer needed to remove an observer from an object:

> In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated.

However, block based observers need to be un-registered as before:

> Block based observers via the -[NSNotificationCenter addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock] method still need to be un-registered when no longer in use since the system still holds a strong reference to these observers.

More information can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-FoundationOlderNotes/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter